# Link unclickable (covered by tag?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i found a nice website / template in the internet, where i started to look a bit a the code.

But unfortunately i don't understand an important part.
The gallery looks like this:

```
<a href="">
   <img src="">
   <h2>...</h2>
</a>
```

But somehow the link don't work. In this demo the link is simply '#', but not even this works (the linkpath is shown on the browser's bottom left)

[image: On Hover the Link is to see, but on click nothing happens]

I have already downloaded this project from github and added my links, but it don't work.

Does someone understand this (maybe stupid) issue? 
Is the link covered from the img tag?

Thank you very much for your help

========================================================================

The demo can be found at: https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingHeaderLayout/

```html
<link href="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingHeaderLayout/css/layout-simple.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingHeaderLayout/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="container" class="container container--open">

  <section class="items-wrap">
    <a href="/album" class="item">
      <img class="item__image" src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingHeaderLayout/img/item01.jpg" alt="item01">
      <h2 class="item__title">Magnificence</h2>
    </a>
  </section>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: `href='#'` just targets the same page. What are you trying to do? You also have a weird scroll issue.

Comment: What is this `internetm` the interwebs?

Comment: @Tibs I'm an apprentice in informatics. I try to take some websites and try locally some things.. But even if i run the application locally, and even when i write href="/albums" or whatever, the link don't work. It's displayed as seen on the pictures bottom left, but by clicking there is no action performed

Comment: @PHPglue Yes i know of course what # means. But i'm running the project also locally, and even if i add a link into the href, the link is shown correctly (like on the pictures bottom) but no action performed by click.

But even if href is # now, at least then the url from the website should change from '...HeaderLayout/' to '...HeaderLayout/#'. Not?

Comment: Can you share some helpful code snippets (probably from jsfiddle) so we can help you with this? Thanks

Comment: You have to look for a javascript event handler that may be blocking the image click, that is my guess.

Comment: `href='index.html'` on `Simple` link. Learn how to use your Inspector.

Comment: @PHPglue When i write href="https:google.com" then it works. But i want the link to '/album'.. So when i'm on 'test.com' then i want to be after on 'test.com/album'   but this link is not working..

It's displayed correctly as 'test.com/album' and when i make a rightclick on then i can open the link in a new tab. but by clicking nothing is working

Comment: That's just a folder without a mod rewrite.

Comment: Running your code above, the link works (but obviously gets a 404 because it can't find /album)

Comment: yes, as the comment above states, the code in the snippet works. but i am guessing that because it is free of the code that is blocking the click event. there is probably a `e.preventDefault()` on the links, in the JS code somewhere.

Comment: there is nothing in the html that is preventing the click from working that i can see.